# JSON Сериализация Dictionary

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
[System.Serializable]    

public class SizeDBData
    {
        public string SizeName;
        public string Six_two_six;
        public string Foot_type;
        public string Fabric;
        public string RangeName;
    }


public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<SizeDBData>>> Sizes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<SizeDBData>>>();
```

Помогите плиз, как можно такое заджейсонить. Использую юнити. `JsonUtility.ToJson(Sizes)` не помогает

```
 foreach (var style in Styles)
 {
      yield return StartCoroutine(FetchSizeByStyle(style.StyleName));
 }

Debug.LogError(JsonUtility.ToJson(Sizes));

private IEnumerator FetchSizeByStyle(string _style)
    {
        UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get("url");
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(uwr.downloadHandler.text);

        //List<SizeDBData> size = new List<SizeDBData>();

        foreach (var listItem in obj.list)
        {
            string style = listItem["range_name"].str;
            if (!Sizes.ContainsKey(style))
            {
                Sizes.Add(style, new Dictionary<string, List<SizeDBData>>());
            }

            string size = listItem ["size"].str;
            if (!Sizes[style].ContainsKey(size))
            {
                Sizes [style].Add(size,new List<SizeDBData>());
            }

            var sizeData = new SizeDBData(listItem ["size"].str,listItem ["six_two_six"].str,listItem ["foot_type"].str,listItem ["fabric"].str,listItem ["range_name"].str);

            Sizes [style][size].Add(sizeData);
        }

        //Sizes.Add(_style,size);
    }
```

Comment: Что значит `не помогает`?

Comment: пустая строка в ответ

Comment: а сам словарь заполненный?

Comment: заполнен, проверенно

Comment: Код заполнения и сериализации в студию

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pdz5f3 http://prntscr.com/pdz53b

Comment: в вопрос, все в вопрос, и код добавляйте в вопрос текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: ответил, код отправил

Comment: Сериализация должна быть проще. Это пример из другой библиотеки. Посмотрите документацию к вашей библиотеки, должно быть что то подобное. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ну, самый простой вариант сериализуемого словаря с использованием Unity функционала выглядит примерно так:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    #region Fields

    [SerializeField]
    List<TKey> _keys;

    [SerializeField]
    List<TValue> _values;

    #endregion Fields
    #region Serialization

    void ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _keys.Count; i++)
        {
            var key = _keys[i];
            var value = _values[i];
            Add(key, value);
        }

        _keys.Clear();
        _values.Clear();
    }

    void ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        _keys = new List<TKey>(Count);
        _values = new List<TValue>(Count);
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            _keys.Add(item.Key);
            _values.Add(item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

У него есть проблема с созданием мусорных массивов, если сам словарь большой - то он сначала создаст словарь под 0 значений. Потом под 4, 16 и т.д. другими словами несколько массивов элементов уйдут в сборщик мусора.

При этом словарь не имеет публичных методов для Resize-а. Я решал путём выковыривания метода через рефлексию.